# Rake Aborted! "Don't know how to build task 'dropbox:authorize'"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, dropbox

Working with rails and my application, and bumped into a problem. I've come to the step where I need to install dropbox, and incorporate it to my code. The first step was to install the dropbox gem, and that happened with ease. Then I had to complete the migration, which was also a success. Then it came to the problem to rake dropbox, which the problem happend.

This is the code that I put into my command line:

```
rake dropbox:authorize APP_KEY=your_app_key APP_SECRET=your_app_secret ACCESS_TYPE= dropbox | app_folder.
```

Of course I put my key and secret code into the code, but when I pressed enter, I got the following error.

rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'dropbox:authorize'

Answer (score 1):

You have to choose either dropbox or app_folder for the ACCESS_TYPE parameter.

https://github.com/robin850/carrierwave-dropbox/issues/4

Comment: Oh, I didn't change that part. In my real code i had ACCESS_TYPE= dropbox. And it still doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe it's the space between ACCESS_TYPE= and dropbox?

Comment: No luck, any other ideas?